# Transform to numeric a column with "NULL" values

Tags: r, class, character, transformation, numeric

I've imported a dataset into R where in a column which should be supposed to contain `numeric` values are present `NULL`. This make R set the column class to `character` or `factor` depending on if you are using or not the `stringAsFactors` argument.

To give you and idea this is the structure of the dataset.

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   1016 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Date       : Date, format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
 $ Name       : chr  "Chi" "Chi" "Chi" "Chi" ...
 $ Impressions: chr  "229097" "3323" "70171" "1359" ...
 $ Revenue    : num  533.78 11.62 346.16 3.36 1282.28 ...
 $ Clicks     : num  472 13 369 1 963 161 1 7 317 21 ...
 $ CTR        : chr  "0.21" "0.39" "0.53" "0.07" ...
 $ PCC        : chr  "32" "2" "18" "0" ...
 $ PCOV       : chr  "3470.52" "94.97" "2176.95" "0" ...
 $ PCROI      : chr  "6.5" "8.17" "6.29" "NULL" ...
 $ Dimension  : Factor w/ 11 levels "100x72","1200x627",..: 1 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 1 ...
```

I would like to transform the PCROI column as numeric, but containing `NULL`s it makes this harder.
I've tried to get around the issue setting the value `0` to all observations where current value is `NULL`, but I got the following error message:

```
> data$PCROI[which(data$PCROI == "NULL"), ] <- 0
Error in data$PCROI[which(data$PCROI == "NULL"), ] <- 0 : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

My idea was to change to `0` all the `NULL` observations and afterwards transform all the column to numeric using the `as.numeric` function.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error:

```
data$PCROI[which(data$PCROI == "NULL"), ] <- 0 # will not work
data$PCROI[which(data$PCROI == "NULL")] <- 0 # will work
```

by the way you can say:

```
data$PCROI = as.numeric(data$PCROI)
```

it will convert your "NULL" to NA automatically.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try since the beginning `data$PCROI = as.numeric(data$PCROI)` (!?). Thanks Hans!